# Database returns 0 instead of selected value in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I would like to retrieve the `userInfoId` from the database and pass it into `var` where the Login username is Kenny. However, the value returned to u was 0 instead of the desired value. I have tried selecting another username but the result was still the same.

```
            var u = Database.UserInfo
            .Where(userinfo => userinfo.LoginUserName == "BEN")
            .Select(x=> x.UserInfoId)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put some breakpoints and see what you have inside `u`, Use the query below and you should be good to go. Make sure the table/column names are correct according to your db.

```
int userInfoId = (from x in context.UserInfo
                   where x.LoginUserName == "Kenny"
                   select x.UserInfoId).SingleOrDefault());
if (userInfoId > 0){
    // user exists and do what you wish to next
}
else {
    // user does not exist
}
```

Comment: So your saying to use the same code OP is already using. Hardly an answer!